# converting json array to php to request a webservice

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, rest

I am currently programming a webservice. on of its method is to send some information to delete a user from event. this is [documentation](https://pnlapi.alocom.co/api/documentation):

the json is like this

```
{
  "users": "[users :['userid' : 1, 'role' : 'participant'],['userid' : 2, 'role' : 'teacher'],['userid' : 3, 'role' : 'assistant']]"
}
```

but I always get the error of  "field users is required";

I appreciate any answer. thanks alot

I tried this

```
function delete_user_from_event( $event_id, $user_id ){
        $webService = 'https://pnlapi.alocom.co/api/v1/agents/events/'. $event_id .'/remove-users';
        $params = array(
            'users'  => array(
             'users' => array(
                [
                 'userid'      => $user_id,
                 'role'      => 'participant',
             ] )
            )
         );
         
        return $this -> post_request( $webService, false, $params, 'patch' );
    }
```

but I get error. I think I do not understand json array.

Comment: @hakre Thanks, I edited the link to the documentation. https://pnlapi.alocom.co/api/documentation

Comment: Ignore my json_encode in the previous comment (now deleted), it is not json but exactly the string as given (with single quotes inside the string, that is not JSON). Just provide it that way. No idea what `$this` is, but at the end of the day the API tells you when you're successful. Try with using a verbatim string for testing, and when you get it to run, consider to create an isolated function you can encode an array that way (some kind of array-to-string conversion for this API).